# Adding colorbar to matplotlib axis with make_axes_locatable and fixed imshow aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm trying to plot some array data and add a colorbar to the right of the axis, matching the height and with a set width.

Starting by generating some data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

data = np.random.rand(700, 400)
```

I've got the following function.

```
def plot_data(data, aspect, pad):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    img = ax.imshow(data, aspect=aspect)
    last_axes = plt.gca()
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=pad)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
    plt.sca(last_axes)
```

Running `plot_data(data, None, 0.05)` gives what I would expect - [an image with colorbar taking up 5% of the width, matched to the same height and padded correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mfyl.png)

However running `plot_data(data, 2.5, 0)` results in [a figure with an image that has the correct aspect ratio, but a colorbar that's padded way too much.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia7k4.png) I can correct this by making the padding negative, finding a good value by trial and error. However I need this to be generic and to work without user monitoring.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563858/matplotlib-imshow-fixed-aspect-and-vertical-colorbar-matching-master-axis-height) but the answer doesn't seem to solve this particular case.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been playing with this and it looks like the color bar is always based on the original location of the edge of the data plot. This means that, for positive aspect ratios, the height of the graph stays fixed and the width of the graph is reduced. 
The image is then centered so the padding needs to be used to adjust the color bar respectively (inward) by width - height/aspect

```
width=last_axes.get_position().width
height=last_axes.get_position().height
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=-((width/0.7)-(height/(0.7*aspect)) + pad))
```

The odd thing I encountered is that it's not exactly centering the data but rather the center of the data and axis labels so we have to downscale the adjustment accordingly hence the 1/0.7 in the formula. I realise that this is not perfect as the ticklables are not being reduced by aspect so a linear shift would be more suitable but I've done it now!

please note this DOES NOT work for aspect ratios LESS THAN 1 because at that point the width is fixed and the height gets altered when aspect is applied. I'm gonna keep messing around with it and see if I can generalise for landscape

edit:

Ok, I have it. the append axis function forces the vertical colorbar to be the original height of the plot for some reason. fine for portrait plots but broken for landscape where the data is shrunk vertically but the plot isn't so I had to put a switch case in here's the full code:

```
def plot_data(data, aspect, pad):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    img = ax.imshow(data, aspect=aspect)
    last_axes = plt.gca()
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    if(aspect<1): 
        hscale=aspect
        cbar = fig.colorbar(img,shrink=hscale,pad=(-0.43+pad))
    else:
        hscale=1
        width=last_axes.get_position().width
        height=last_axes.get_position().height
        padfix = -((width/0.7)-(height/(0.7*aspect))) 
        cax = divider.append_axes('right',size='5%', pad=padfix+ pad)
        cbar = fig.colorbar(img,cax=cax)
```

Again there's some weirdness going on with a fixed offset (this time \approx 0.43) this was found by trial and error and may need to be adjusted if plotting *really* long thin plots.

Answer (score 0):

#### A solution to the problem

A "nonlinear regression" with a few approximate values in the interval (1,2.5) gave me:

```
y=a*x^2+b*x+c
a=0.25
b=-1.29
c=1.09
```

Try using:

```
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.25*aspect**2-1.29*aspect+1.09)
```

For now you can't use `None` as aspect when `aspect=1` and you don't need to pass `pad`. Also, this formula works for `aspect>=1`, you may need to get another formula for values less than 1 because the behaviour is really different. For values higher than 2.5 you need to calculate new coefficientes (the explanation is below).

```
def plot_data(data, aspect, pad=None):
    if aspect == None:
        aspect = 1
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    img = ax.imshow(data, aspect=aspect)
    last_axes = plt.gca()
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.25*aspect**2-1.29*aspect+1.09)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(img, cax=cax)
    plt.sca(last_axes)
```

#### About the "nonlinear regression"

To get the coefficients the first thing I needed to do is get a few pairs (aspect, padding). How get them? Trial and error: the first pair is the original (1, 0.05), the others were visually good: (1.5, -0.305), (2, -0.48), (2.5, -0.58). If you see, there is no linearity in the data but lets plot it anyways

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [(1,0.05),(1.5,-0.305),(2,-0.48),(2.5,-0.58)]
plt.plot(*zip(*data))
plt.plot(*zip(*data),'or')
plt.xlabel("aspect")
plt.ylabel("padding")
plt.show()
```

[image: aspect/padding]

Now, lets get the the coefficients doing a curve fitting:

```
fit = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(*zip(*pairs),2)
c,b,a = fit.convert().coef
```

(Yes, I only did a curve fitting with a second-degree polynomial, sorry!) Differences between the values I initially wrote and the one python gives arise because I used other software and I did a round to 2 decimals in most cases.

Why did I use a second degree polynomial (fit(x,y,2))? I tried to keep the model as simple as possible.

```
pairs = [(1,0.05),(1.5,-0.305),(2,-0.48),(2.5,-0.58)]
x = np.linspace(1,2.5,100)
yp = [a*x**2+b*x+c for x in x]
plt.plot(*zip(*pairs),'or', label='pairs')
plt.plot(x,yp,'g', label='Curve fitting')
plt.xlabel("aspect")
plt.ylabel("padding")
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of the fitted curve]

Does this work for values outside [1,2.5]? Not really. For that you should include more points in the curve fitting, maybe change the polynomial of order 2 for, lets say, a logarithmic one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this does seem to work, but could you please explain a bit how this works? I'm not sure how to reproduce the a, b, and c values or why applying them to the formula works.

Comment: Sorry, now I added how I get to those values.